# jQuery get all checked boxes + text inputs in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below markup generated dynamically from a PHP script (meaning there are variable number checkboxes or input fields).

```
<div id="resCondition" class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="apples">I want apples                   
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="pears">I want pears
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">I want</span>
        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" value="0">
        <span class="input-group-addon">forks</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Objective**

How do I get all the checked options together with the input-group value in a single string?
E.g. If the user checks both boxes above and enters 3 in the input field. My returned string will be `apples + pears + 3 forks`. If the user only checks the first box then I will only get `apples`.

**Attempts**

I found code to join all checked boxes into a string with

```
var selected = $('#resCondition input:checked').map(function(i,el){return el.val;}).get().join('+');
```

but I am not sure how I can get the input:number and its accompanying text in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the type of the input, if the type is `number` you can concatenate the value with textContent of the next sibling of the element. Note that you should use `value` instead of `val`, `.val()` is method(and not a property) of jQuery object and here `el` is a HTMLElement object.

```
$('#resCondition').find('input:checked, input[type=number]').map(function(i,el) {
     return   el.type === 'checkbox' 
            ? el.value 
            : el.value > 0 ? el.value + ' ' + $(el).next().text() : null; 
}).get().join(' + ');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekQ5f/

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly~ Thank you for the additional information about using `value` and `el` too.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$( "#resCondition" ).find( "input:checked, input[type=number]" ).map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: I did kinda gloss over the .join( " + " ) and the additional addon part of it now that I re-read the question, but modifying my answer to add that should be a trivial exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You should get all input. then check is its checked or value not zero.

Try this - DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/chokchai/RnfMC/

```
var text = [];

$('#resCondition :input').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked') || parseInt($(this).val()) > 0){
        text.push($(this).val())
    }
})

text = text.join(' ');

alert(text);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use as your requirement

```
var selected = new Array();
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Or take help from http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: that doesnt look quite right. there are no inputs with id's "checkboxes"

Comment: I'm not the one who down-voted, but this just looks like wrong syntax. Your selecting all input with `id="checkboxes"`, that's what `#` selector does. How is that appropriate?